# Polygon from world file

Tags: r, terra

In order to get polygons with the boundary of raster images from .jpg + .jgw pairs,
I'm doing this:

```
library(terra)
r <- rectify(rast("DJI_0371.jpg"))
p <- as.polygons(is.na(r))[1,]
```

But it is quite slow for a long list of jpg + .jgw pairs, I think because of `rectify()`.
Is there a way to get the polygon directly from the imported .jpg + .jgw pairs,
avoiding the `rectify()`? Would this be significantly faster?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0lvezqddapmv1g2/DJI_0371.zip?dl=0

Edit:
Following robertdj:

```
> t0 <- Sys.time()
> r <- rast("DJI_0371.jpg")
Warning message:
[rast] the data in this file are rotated. Use 'rectify' to fix that 
> print(Sys.time()-t0)
Time difference of 0.007530451 secs
> 
> t0 <- Sys.time()
> r2 <- rectify(r)
> print(Sys.time()-t0)
Time difference of 0.1370528 secs
> 
> t0 <- Sys.time()
> p <- as.polygons(is.na(r2))[1,]
> print(Sys.time()-t0)
Time difference of 0.02361417 secs
> t0 <- Sys.time()
> p <- as.polygons(is.na( rectify(rast("DJI_0371.jpg"))))[1,]
Warning message:
[rast] the data in this file are rotated. Use 'rectify' to fix that 
> print(Sys.time()-t0)
Time difference of 0.1690121 secs
```

So the 2nd question is answered: avoiding the `rectify()` would be significantly faster.
The 1st question remains.

Comment: Consider profiling your code to see where the time is *actually* spend. This can be done with the {profviz} package in R.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with gdalUtilitis::gdalinfo()

```
> t0 <- Sys.time()
> a <- gdalinfo("DJI_0371.jpg", json=TRUE, quiet=TRUE)
> a <- jsonify::from_json(a)
> a <- matrix(unlist(a$cornerCoordinates)[1:8], nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)
> colnames(a) <- c("lon", "lat") 
> p <- vect(a,"polygons")
> print(Sys.time()-t0)
Time difference of 0.009047747 secs
> plot(p)
```